# SQL VIEW combine tables

Tags: sql, view

I have two tables in my database which I try to combine through a view, where the `id` and `user_id` should match up. I have checked out UNION ALL, but this doesn't seem to be the solution since the order of the entities in the tables can be different and they should be matched.

**users**:

```
id    email              password
--------------------------------------
1     eric@test.com      sdgsdhdfhs
2     john@test.com      dfgsdgdfhg
3     mary@test.com      plkdfjvjvv
```

**permissions**:

```
index    user_id     allow_read   allow_write   allow_delete
-------------------------------------------------------------
1        2           1            0             1
2        3           1            1             1
3        1           0            0             0
```

which should become: (@Gordon Linoff)

```
id    email              password       allow_read   allow_write   allow_delete
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     eric@test.com      sdgsdhdfhs     0            0             0
2     john@test.com      dfgsdgdfhg     1            0             1
3     mary@test.com      plkdfjvjvv     1            1             1
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  I suspect you just want `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly create a view with both the table attributes. The example has one-to-one mapping between two tables, i.e. for every `id` in `users` table there is exactly one row in `permissions` with `user_id = id`. If that is the case then `inner join` might work. If you only care about users table, you can use `left join`. I have tested this query, [please find the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c4e26/3):

```
CREATE VIEW joined_table_view AS
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.password, p.user_id, p.allow_read, p.allow_write, p.allow_delete
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN permissions p
ON u.id = p.user_id;
```

Further, if you want to know more joins refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join). Shall update sqlfiddle once I test it.

Comment: To be clear:
It's all about the "users" table. IF available I want to add the columns of the "permissions" table. If not; then the columns should be just NULL. Their may not be an entity in the "permissions" table, but if there is, it is only 1.

Comment: Updated answer @Rick

Comment: I have created a fiddle that shows the `LEFT JOIN` works @Rick

Comment: I currently have * for SELECT, but how would I combine all columns but DO NOT combine/include "user_id"-column (from the LEFT JOIN table(s))